# Can't get product manufacturer attribute in my custom module

Tags: magento2

I already searched here, but none answers have work.

I have a custom module, where I get a list of products from one category setted by user, it is coded in a Helper class:

```
public function getConfigCategory()
{
    $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load('CONFIGURATION');
    return $category;
}

public function getFilteredProducts()
{
    return $this->getConfigCategory()->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*'); 
}
```

So, with this I have a list of products, wich one foreach (in a Model class), but when I try to get the manufacturer attribute, it always return null.

```
$brand = $product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
```

$brand is always null, I have tried to reload $product with this:

```
$product = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product->getId());
```

But the result is always the same, any ideia? Thanks in advance.

**I'm using the sample data, and I have bundle items**

Comment: Do you get your `manufacture` in `$product` object?

Comment: Yes, with the `getAttributeText` method.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
```

You may need to set your attribute up so attribute is visible in frontend also, this may solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for answering, so I try it and returns **No** ...

Comment: Is this just a plain text attribute?

Comment: No, is a drop down, wich the user must fill, in my store this have brands like Nike, Puma, etc. Is an magento native field.

Comment: Did you check the attribute set to visible on frontend? That seems to work for my dropdowns. Not sure maybe try a reindex also?

Comment: Yes, is setted as visible, clean cache and reindex, but still returning **No** =/

Comment: Does $product->getManufacturer(); return anything? That for me returns the ID.

Comment: Return null for me, why?

Comment: Just really not sure why this isn't working for you, "Used in Product Listing" was what i meant for the attribute that is set to yes? Withing storefront properties